# How to properly use css will-change property?

Tags: performance, css, web, web-platforms

Can anyone explain me how to use this property the right way by example?
I made a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zlaja/hnb1qbtv/1/
and I wonder where to use this property in CSS or JS ?

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.l-header {
    width: 300px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: red;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    will-change: transform;
    /*Is this the right place ???*/
}
a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
.toggle-header {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


<a href="#">Menu</a>
<header class="l-header"></header>


var menu = document.querySelector("a"),
    header = document.querySelector(".l-header");

var toogle = function () {
    header.classList.toggle("toggle-header");
}

menu.addEventListener("click", toogle, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: it's likely that you will often pair this with JS, to inject the `will-change` property when parts of the page are made interactive, to allow the browser to perf-optimize them before the user interacts with them.

The "long" answer: read [Sara Soueidan's article on dev.opera.com](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-will-change-property/).

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, your example is pretty ok. However, if you for some reason did *not* want to apply the 3d transform initial state until you know for sure your JS is loaded (which may be a good idea), you'd add that + the `will-change` stuff using JS on page init, for example.

Comment: But I guess the main reason for there not being so many examples yet is that this is really really new stuff. :-)

Comment: I am preparing myself for the future :-P. Spec needs to be more clear on this property definitely. I will try to find answer on this from somebody of spec writers and share here if I get it.

Comment: From **Tab Atkins**:

It's probably fine to just add `"nav { will-change: transform; }"`, like
you did in that example.

No need to worry about your will-changes if there are just a few.

~TJ